# Averaging Correlations

Tags: time-series, correlation

I am working with patient experience data where patients answer questions regarding their stay at the hospital. Each question is then given a correlation value as it relates to the final "overall experience" question. The data is in 6 month intervals with each question having different correlation values for each 6 month interval.

How can I get one correlation value for 2 years worth of data from four 6 month intervals, i.e., four correlation values?

Comment: You can average the [Fisher transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_transformation) of r-scores, if the N's are the same, or perform a weighted average, if they are not. But, I suspect you'll want to take the temporal aspects of this situation into account, if you want an accurate answer.

Comment: Why don't just merge the data and compute one correlation value?

Comment: A prior question is whether the different correlations are really different. If so, averaging may not really help. If so, you could think about looking at different effects in a regression model.

Comment: Are you perhaps asking the same thing as http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8019/averaging-correlation-values?  If not, how does your situation differ?