# Aggregating many correlations

Tags: time-series, correlation, python, statsmodels

I have measurements of covarying time-series. $X$ and $Y$ both vary in time, but I am interested in finding the correlation between $X$ and $Y$.

I have around 1500 measurements (individual timeseries) for $X$ and $Y$ and am trying to find their correlation. Obviously I cannot simply find the correlation coefficients for $X_i$ and $Y_i$ individually, and then average them (as per the answers in this question [Averaging correlation values](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8019/averaging-correlation-values))

Additionally I cannot use the linear model suggested in that question because I am not simply plotting the correlation of many $Y$s against 1 $X$.

Can anyone suggest where to go from here? Timeseries pair of $X$ and $Y$ are independent and come from a single individual in the population. Simply aggregating all of the points into a giant dataset is not suitable for this reason either.

I'm using `statsmodels` in Python, but am also happy to use R.

Edit:

Is it correct to group all of my data into a dataframe with columns:
X, Y, ID where ID is a dummy variable for each timeseries.

Then I can use any package I want to fit a linear model like X ~ Y + C(ID)?

Comment: Could you explain the sense in which you use "correlation" here?  Ordinarily we think of it as a statistical measure of association of paired (x,y) data.  What precludes examining all such pairs that you might have and applying a standard formula?

Comment: Correlation as in Pearson's correlation coefficient. I can individually generate 1500 R values, but this isn't meaningful for me, as I want to check what is happening at a population level. 

The experiment is single cell data of growth rate vs the levels of some protein. I want to know how on the population level this data is correlated over time.

I wonder, can I calculate the covariance of each pair and average over all covariances?

Comment: The part I don't quite understand is this: because each R value you generate is based on a set of $(x,y)$ data, that means you have a large dataset of all 1500 groups.  That dataset is a much larger set of the collected $(x,y)$ data.  What would be the matter with computing its correlation coefficient?  There are many conceivable answers, but one of them is "nothing."

Comment: I am not quite sure if I understood your question correctly, it would be better if you could include at least a chunk of your dataset. But I suppose you need to use a VAR or Vector autoregressive model which is designed to deal with covarying time series and it regresses the time series on each others and give you the coefficient of your interest. check this: https://www.machinelearningplus.com/time-series/vector-autoregression-examples-python/

Comment: @whuber because each set of $(x,y)$ data has a different slope, and so by aggregating everything, the correlation coefficient of the entire dataset is lower than all individual correlation coefficients.

Comment: That's precisely why I am asking for clarification, because it raises the fundamental question of what your combined correlation is intended to represent.  Exactly what property of this collection of time series are you trying to quantify?  How would you interpret it?

Comment: Dear @whuber. My data is protein expression over time, and growth rate over time. This was measured in about 1500 individual cells, so 1500 (x(t),y(t) series). I'm looking to report on how growth rate and protein are correlated. So it's easy to just check the correlation coefficients or covariances for individual cells, but I'm wondering if there's something which aggregates all these correlations. Currently I'm fitting a model where each cell gets an ID, which is a dummy variable, and so I fit a model like  X ~ Y + C(ID).